# Modifying an android app with integrated google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, apk

I found a free android app on Google Play that uses google maps and communicates with the author's website. I modified it with text editor, packed back into an .apk file and signed it with free signing tools found on the web and installed successfully onto my phone. It works great but it cannot show google maps anymore.
My questions:

1. Is it illegal to modify an android app and use it personally on my phone?
2. Can Google detect that the app is trying to access gmaps with a different signature and can I get punished or will Google inform the author?
3. Can I get a signing key and register it on gmaps and can I use it to sign the app to enable gmaps inside the app?
4. Will google detect that the same app is using their gmap services with different signature?
5. Can I cause problems to author with this modification?

Thank you in advance,
Andrysh5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it illegal to modify an android app and use it personally on my phone?

If it's done for an educational purpose, it's not much of a problem but keep it to yourself and don't distribute it to others.

> Can Google detect that the app is trying to access gmaps with a different signature and can I get punished or will Google inform the author?

The app that you modified is most likely using Google Maps v2 API which requires an apikey and that particular apikey is only registered to the signature of the author of the app. I think your free signing tool is using a different keystore or jks file and changes the signature. As result, the API asks Google for it's Maps resources with a signature that doesn't belong to the apikey.

> Can I get a signing key and register it on gmaps and can I use it to sign the app to enable gmaps inside the app?

You need to obtain the sha1 signature of the key and indeed register it on Google Developer Console. If you can rebuild the modified apk with YOUR key, then it would be possible indeed.

> Will google detect that the same app is using their gmap services with different signature?

Yes but it's not like they will do anything about it. If you signature doesn't match the apikey, you won't receive their resources. It's not big of a deal.

> Can I cause problems to author with this modification?

If you use it for an educational purpose, then no not really but don't screw around with his webserver or anything else that could possibly harm his project. Keep in mind that he worked on it and that you should respect his effort in creating the app.

--

You could contact the author of the app and ask for his permission to modify his app and perhaps help him out in improving his app. It would be nice that he could benefit from your security improvements or whatsoever as you're using his apk file.

As I said; please don't distribute it to other nor upload it somewhere online.